What is the topological classification of spaces with non-constant cauchy sequences?
To be clear, I'm not asking about completeness of the space, just if there is some classification that can be placed on spaces where there exists a Cauchy sequence that is (eventually) non-constant. There are some trivial properties such a space has to have:

non-finite
distance

Clearly these terms are not enough to classify such a space as the natural numbers act as a counter example, so I'm curious as to what's missing. Thanks for the help!

What do you mean with "distance" as a property?

You can also define Cauchy sequences using a uniformity, which doesn't necessarily come from a metric.

If you have a metric (distance) and at least one point which is not an isolated point, you have such a Cauchy sequence. You obviously need a distance, since Cauchy sequences are defined by distances. $(0,1)$ and $(-\infty,\infty)$ are homeomorphic, but some Cauchy sequences in $(0,1)$ correspond to sequences which are not Cauchy in $(-\infty,\infty).$

But that icondition is sufficient, not necessary.
